# jmeter Distributed Load Testing - java.rmi.ServerException

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, distributed

I am sorry if I am asking a wrong question, I am new to Jmeter.

I am trying to run distributed load on slave machine.

While running test with slave machine `[ set properties file at master machine]` and Slave Jmeter-server is running

Getting below exception:

> Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException:
> RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
> java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager; local class
> incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 235, local class
> serialVersionUID = 236

Could you please help with above error.

Comment: You have different JMeter versions in slave and master

Answer (score 0):

Given you have different values in [this line](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/CookieManager.java#L53)

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 234L;
```

it means that the master and the slave are running different version of JMeter

You need to use the **same version of JMeter** for the master and the slave(s), according to JMeter Best Practices [it needs to be the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)

also it's recommended to use:

1. The same version of Java
2. The same [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) if any
3. If your test uses external data files (like CSV) or 3rd-party .jar files you need to manually copy them to the slaves prior to running the test

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)